# HttpPost response doesn't return the json object

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, http-get

I'm currently working on a project which needs to send a post request and get a json object from the server. Earlier I used Get method to access the json object. It worked fine. But because of some server changes I had to move to post method. Then it doesn't return me the json object that I got earlier from the 'get' method. I tried my best to come up with a solution but couldn't. Highly appreciate if anyone can help me to get through this problem.

```
private AdSniperAdObjectResponse postData(String url) {
    //Bundle b = new Bundle();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getThreadSafeClient();
    //Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", "-33.8736"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", "151.207"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "35"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", "All"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

Above is the code that I use. Earlier I used HttpGet class. For HttpPost, the 'resp'variable is always null. Don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: And I found out that status code of the response is 400. That means something wrong with the request..

Answer (score 1):

should't this be like

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        if (httpResponse  != null) {
            String resp = httpResponse.toString();
```

and in case if server return JSONString..

```
say JSONObject data = new JSONObject(resp);
```

and then get values..

Comment: @Sandy..no sandy..it still gives me a null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof  (List<NameValuePair> ));
```

try with this and pass your data using this

```
jsonSerializer.WriteObject(reqStream, nameValuePairs );
                reqStream.Close();
```

and again deserialize the response whatever you are getting

Comment: the thing is that before it goes to the json parts, when I try to convert that httpResponse to a string, it gives me a null value. If I can get the json string from the response other parts are ok..btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to get the `HttpEntity`, you should get the `StatusLine` and check that the status code is what you expect.  I suspect that the real problem is that the server is sending an error response of some kind.  And since you used an "Accept" header to request a JSON response, it is likely that the server is not sending any diagnostics in the response body ... so it is empty.

Comment: ..do u know how to check the status line of the httppost response

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the solution. It worked when I commented the following two lines.

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");
```

So thanks everyone for your answers. Highly appreciate.